# Content not found Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have created my app page on Facebook. I have added the required setting like Google Play Package Name, Class name and key hashes but still when try to access that app page it is showing below given error instead of taking us to play store. I have search a lot in web but did not get the relevant post. But I assume this issue can be fixed by Facebook settings. I would really appreciate any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either they deactivated or deleted their account, got suspended by Facebook or else they blocked you.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these could be a reason:

- Could be a browser problem. Try to delete cache of the browser and try to open with other browsers or other systems.
- Unpublished your page and Published your page again. See [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/184605634921611/?ref=u2u).
- Could be a reason Facebook has removed the content of that page and now you can not access it.

Comment: Actually its play store URL. When clicking on that app page it should redirect to play store